# Extjs 4.2.1 - data store load all fields from the server

Tags: extjs, extjs4, datastore

Is there a way to make the data store to create a model containing all the fields retrieved from the server?

Lets say we have on the server side the object:

```
User : {
    name: "...",
    phone: "...",
    Address: {
        street: "...",
        country: "...",
    },
    ...
    ...
}
```

And we use the following store to load this user:

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
 proxy: {
     type: 'ajax',
     url: '...',
     reader: {
         type: 'json',
         root: 'users'
     }
 },
 fields :[name, phone],
 autoLoad: true
});
```

Is there a way to config the fields inside the data store to retrieve all the fields from the user without a specific mapping like the example (name, phone)? I mean, can I put something like ** in the **fields** attribute that will say to the data store, map all the fields retrieved as they are, and the result will be a store with the user's name, phone and address?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

yes it is possible there is proper code snipet which will help you

```
    var fields = [];


     Ext.each(me.dataFromServer, function (record) {
         fields.push({
             name: record.fieldName
         });

      });

    var myModel =  Ext.define('myModelName',{
         extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        idProperty: 'id', //some field
         fields: fields
     });
```

and our store looks like this

```
me.store = Ext.create('yourStore',{
         model: myModel
     });
```

and thic code is located in initComponent:

Your store:

```
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
//model: null,
```

without model.

Comment: Where should I put this code:                                             Ext.each(me.dataFromServer, function (record) {
         fields.push({
             name: record.fieldName
         });

      });

Comment: everything in your initComponent: function() {
  var me = this;
till before me.callParent();

Comment: Good idea. I found out that every record in the store has **raw** attribute which holds the full data of that record from the server. Eventually I used this attribute. Thanks anyway man.